# Removing selected item in list

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the listview like as below in Xaml

```xml
<ListView x:Name="PreviousChatList" ItemsSource="{Binding PreviousMessagesList}" Grid.Row="0" ItemSelected="DeleteMessage">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding }" FontSize="12" TextColor="Black"/>
                                <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ButtonsStackvisibility}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Button Text="Delete" TextColor="Brown" Clicked="DeleteClicked">></Button>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Here i would like to make `ButtonsStackvisibility`true when item in list is selected,

```cs
 private void DeleteMessage(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     _chatWindowViewModel.ButtonsStackvisibility = true;
     ApplicationContext.seletedMessageToDelete = e.SelectedItem.ToString();
 }
```

And when `DeleteClicked` is clicked

```cs
 private void DeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    _chatWindowViewModel.MessagesList.Remove(ApplicationContext.seletedMessageToDelete);
 },
```

But the problem i am facing here is,the item is not removing and visibility is not working.How to solve this?

Comment: What is the data type of PreviousMessagesList? You just need to use an Observable Collection

Comment: @EstebanVerbel, Its string and i am using Observable Collection.

Comment: Have you tried removing the message directly from PreviousMessagesList property?

Comment: and if that is not working you can try this RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PreviousMessagesList));

Comment: @EstebanVerbel,Thank you,when i tried deleting from   PreviousMessagesList directly items are removing but `ButtonsStackvisibility` is not working.

Comment: So basically you want to set ButtonsStackvisibility to false to hide it but it is not working. I misunderstood your question initially. Any item inside the listview is bound to the ItemsSource objects. To solve the problem it is necessary to bind the ButtonsStackvisibility by referencing the Root of the ViewModel (BindingContext)

Comment: Try this on the StackLayout of the buttom. IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=PreviousChatList}, Path=BindingContext.ButtonsStackvisibility}"

Comment: That would hide all the buttons. I am not sure how you are defining ButtonsStackvisibility